# how change order of columns in csv file using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 csv files which I have to merge and but before that I have to prepare then to have same columns order. All works fine except for I cannot figure out so far how change order of columns in output file. I can select columns which I want and other skips fine but what if I want to swap some? I thought that putting in proper order in fieldinfo array would do the trick but no. I want to swap 8 with 6.

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Filenamenew, Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow _
    :=2, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
    Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 3), Array(2, 9), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 9), Array(5, 9), Array(8, 1), Array(7, 9), Array(6, 1))

    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Wb.SaveAs Filename:=LBname, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum, _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Wb.Close savechanges:=False
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The **best** way to do this is to change the output of whatever is creating the CSV file you need to change.  I assume you don't have access to that for whatever reason, so this will get the job done:

```
Sub swapColumns(first As Integer, second As Integer)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\root\test.csv")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    If first > second Then
        Dim i As Integer
        i = first
        first = second
        second = i
    ElseIf first = second Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ws.Columns(second).Cut
    ws.Columns(first).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ws.Columns(first + 1).Cut
    ws.Columns(second + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End Sub
```

You can call this Sub from your existing code with `swapColumns 6, 8`

Comment: Excellent - glad I could help! If this has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to the left of this answer. Doing this helps you in the future as sometimes people check how often you accept answers before they work on an answer for you - and you get 2 reputation points as well.